# Generating parquet files - differences between R and Python

Tags: r, parquet, dask, apache-drill, fastparquet

We have generated a `parquet` file in  `Dask` (Python) and with `Drill` (R using the `Sergeant`  packet ).  We have noticed a few issues:

1. The format of the `Dask` (i.e. `fastparquet`) has a `_metadata` and a `_common_metadata` files while the `parquet` file in `R \ Drill` does not have these files and have `parquet.crc` files instead (which can be deleted). what is the difference between these `parquet` implementations?

Comment: I understand that there are various [parquet versions](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/06/28/use-parquet) but it is difficult to understand the differences

Comment: You should post these three questions as separate ones on Stack Overflow. Posting multiple ones as a single instance is quite hard to answer and integrate into the SO UI.

Comment: Thx for the input - Will do so

Answer (score 3):

(only answering to 1), please post separate questions to make it easier to answer)

`_metadata` and `_common_metadata` are helper files that are not required for a Parquet dataset, these ones are used by Spark/Dask/Hive/... to infer the metadata of all Parquet files of a dataset without the need to read the footer of all files. In constrast to this, Apache Drill generates a similar file in each folder (on demand) that contains all footers of all Parquet files. Only on the first query on a dataset all files are read, further queries will only read the file that caches all footers.

Tools using `_metadata` and `_common_metadata` should be able to leverage them to have faster execution times but not depend on them for operations. In the case that they are non-existent, the query engine then simply needs to read all footers.

Comment: Quite correct. In addition, fastparquet (the library that dask will have used to create the files) can also read a list of parquet data files without a `_metadata`, but initially loading metadata will be slower. Spark used to make these files, but no longer does, I believe hive still does.