# Cross read parquet files between R and Python

Tags: r, parquet, dask

We have generated a parquet files, one in `Dask` (Python) and another with `R Drill` (using the `Sergeant` packet ). They use a different implementations of `parquet` [see my other parquet question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415829/generating-parquet-files-differences-between-r-and-python/45416605#45416605)

We are not able to cross read the files (the python can't read the R file and vice versa).
When reading the Python parquet file in the R environment we receive the following error: `system error: Illegalstatexception: UTF8 can only annotate binary filed` .
When reading the R/Drill parquet file in Dask we get an `FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] no such file or directory ...\_metadata`  (which is self explanatory).
What are the options to cross read parquet files between R and Python?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read drill-like parquet data-sets with fastparquet/dask, you need to pas a list of the filenames, e.g.,

```
files = glob.glob('mydata/*/*.parquet')
df = dd.read_parquet(files)
```

The error from going in the other direction might be a bug, or (gathering from your other question), may indicate that you used fixed-length strings, but drill/R doesn't support them.